# systemd user unit not started after reboot until user logs in

Tags: linux, systemd, systemctl

I have a systemd user unit that is activated and has a timer to run every day at a certain time. The problem I am having is that if the server is rebooted (and I don't know when that might happen) the service stops running and then I eventually notice the process has not run for a while and I login... It then starts right when I login and begins to run.

How can I make it so that it automatically resumes the timer/service when the server is rebooted so I can avoid having random outages of my process?

service file

```
[Unit]
Description=daily process update
AssertHost=ai1

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/st2/process
ExecStart=/home/user/.venv/env/bin/python main.py --update_data

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

timer file

```
[Unit]
Description=run process update daily
AssertHost=myserver

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 14:20:00
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

installed with the following script

```
        # systemd does not support symlinks across partitions, copy service and timer to user dir
        # enable timer which calls service by the same name
        # https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083537/how-do-i-properly-install-a-systemd-timer-and-service
        cp ./stock-update.service /home/user/.config/systemd/user/process-update.service
        cp ./stock-update.timer /home/user/.config/systemd/user/process-update.timer
        systemctl --user disable process-update.timer
        systemctl --user daemon-reload
        systemctl --user enable --now process-update.timer
```

Answer (score 4):

You can enable [lingering](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/loginctl.html#enable-linger%20USER%E2%80%A6) for a systemd user instance by running `loginctl enable-linger $USER` for the user.